# Move all rows with errors in processing into another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm converting some strings to datetime with the following command:

```
polly_jun_jul_trans['Imp_Trans_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(polly_jun_jul_trans['Imp_Trans_Date'])
polly_jun_jul_trans['Imposition_Date_of_Hearing'] = pd.to_datetime(polly_jun_jul_trans['Imposition_Date_of_Hearing'])
```

However some of my values have errors in them, like so: ('Unknown string format:', '29/06n2018').

Whats the best way to move all the rows that throw up errors in either of the columns to another dataframe, by that I mean concatenate any error-rows that come up with the second command, onto the error-rows that came up with the first command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the union of the troublesome rows via [`pd.Series.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html). This means if *either* of the 2 `datetime` conversions fail for a row, then that row will give `False`; otherwise `True`.

```
df['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'], errors='coerce')
df['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col2'], errors='coerce')

error_bool = df['col1'].isnull() | df['col2'].isnull()
```

Then use Boolean indexing:

```
main = df[~error_bool].copy()
errors = df[error_bool].copy()
```

I have used [`pd.DataFrame.copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) to guarantee the new dataframes will no longer reference the original dataframe containing all rows.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of your original question, pertaining to how to remove rows that raise errors.

You can use the `errors` keyword of `pd.to_datetime()`, shown below:

> errors : {‘ignore’, ‘raise’, ‘coerce’}, default ‘raise’
>
> If ‘raise’, then invalid parsing will raise an exception If ‘coerce’,
>   then invalid parsing will be set as NaT If ‘ignore’, then invalid
>   parsing will return the input

You can use `pd.to_datetime( ____, errors='coerce')` and then use `dropna()`.